# India to Belarus by Train + Road

Tags: india, belarus

Is it possible to travel to Belarus from India by both train & bus? And if possible, then in which path is it possible? Is it the route

> India > Nepal > Tibet > Tajikistan > Uzbekistan > Kazakhstan > Russia > Ukrain > Belarus?

Comment: I've done it from London to Tajikistan, so you'd just need to confirm the rest

Comment: I would rather try this via Iran and Turkey instead, without crossing the Himalaya.

Answer (score 2):

Using Rome2Rio, I believe this is theoretically possible via Lhasa, Dushanbe, Qarshi, and Moscow, but it would take about two weeks. Is this for a bet?

Comment: Why would it be for a bet?  It sounds like an amazing journey (not sure why stop in Belarus though).